# "No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen" using OpenURI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, open-uri

I've recently run into a problem using OpenURI. Every `open` method results in the following error:

```
"No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen".
```

My code looks simply like the following:

```
data = open("http://google.ca/")
```

I noticed the error shortly after adding `gem 'nokogiri'` to my `Gemfile` and running `bundle install`, though I have no indication of whether or not this caused the problem and have since removed the entry with no positive impact on the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try to write `require 'open-uri'` before your code.

Comment: whay is that after requiring that worked? In my local system i did not had to require it but i had to require it in my production server code.

Comment: Maybe you have development dependency which has this requirement.

Answer (score 29):

I am using Ruby 3.0.1 and a part from the:

```
require "open-uri"
```

I have to explicitly call `URI.open` instead of just `open`:

```
data = URI.open("http://google.ca/")
```

Maybe it is something on new Ruby versions

Comment: Here are [the relevant commit](https://github.com/ruby/open-uri/commit/53862fa35887a34a8060aebf2241874240c2986a) and [issue](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/15893).

Comment: solved the issue on ruby 3.1.2